# Where I'm wrong? Why my solution is wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I'm learning Linear Algebra right now and at current about how to find rank of any given matrix. I'm confused in a problem from sometime. I don't know where I am wrong with the solution. Please have a look at the images.
 **My Solution** [image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

**Solution given in my book**[image: Image 3]
The book tells that the given matrix will be of 2 rank and I think my solution will show rank 1. Please help. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: In $R_2 \rightarrow R_2 + \frac12 R_4$: you forgot to do something.

Comment: Yes, you're forgetting to do the operation on the whole row or the whole column in several cases (also in $C_4 \to C_4+2C_2$, for example).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint-$1$:** Observe that $C_1 \& C_2$ are linearly independent. Reason there is no such $\alpha$ for which $C_2 = \alpha C_1$ ($1=\alpha\cdot0$).
$$C_3 = -3C_2+C_1 \dots (1)$$
$$C_4 = C_1-C_2 \dots (2)$$

**Hint-$2$:** Use Elementary Row Operators' to get the Row Reduced Echelon form. Take any standard text book, and you will find it there.